# Pyautogui click speed

Tags: pyautogui

I need more clicking speed using pyautogui, max cps that I got is 75.
The only way to increase the speed I found is by changing pyautogui.PAUSE.
How can I get more, or there is a limit?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805649/how-to-increase-number-of-clicks-per-second-with-pyautogui#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20pyautogui.,most%2010%20clicks%20per%20second.&text=for%20example%20will%20reduce%20the,if%20your%20hardware%20supports%20it. ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way related to pyautogui.PAUSE. I tried it, and it worked pretty fast

```
from pyautogui import *
from time import *

for i in range(10):
    click()
    sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue you are having is directly related to the hardware. Even if I set
`pyautogui.PAUSE = 0`
my cps is still capped at about 32. You aren't doing anything wrong, as far as I know. But if I did get something wrong, feel free to correct me.

EDIT: OK, I'm stupid. Setting `pyautogui.PAUSE = 0` is actually LESS efficient (for me) than setting it to be very low. Set `pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.00001`. I know it's weird, but I get 1000+ CPS